# Возвращение переменных

Tags: html, javascript

Нужно, чтобы человек ввел первое число, затем второе, затем вывелся их результат. Какие есть предложения? Идея с диалогом внутри первого диалога неудачна!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
   var someNumber = parseInt(prompt("Введите число"));
   var someAnotherNumber = parseInt(prompt("Введите еще одно число"));
   //ну а дальше уже разберетесь
}
```